# python - webdriver and asyncio

Tags: python, selenium, asynchronous, webdriver, python-asyncio

Is it possible open browser for each task firstly, and load links after that ?
This code raises an error

```
import asyncio
from selenium import webdriver

async def get_html(url):
    driver = await webdriver.Chrome()
    response = await driver.get(url)
```

TypeError: object WebDriver can't be used in 'await' expression

Answer (score 23):

The problem was discussed at: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3399

If you want to have async webdrivers, there are two libraries you can use:

- https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python
- https://github.com/HDE/arsenic

Answer (score 21):

If you want to use Selenium in an async fashion I would suggest using multiple instances of the Driver and a executor like this:

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor

from selenium import webdriver

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(10)


def scrape(url, *, loop):
    loop.run_in_executor(executor, scraper, url)


def scraper(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver")
    driver.get(url)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
for url in ["https://google.de"] * 2:
    scrape(url, loop=loop)

loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*asyncio.all_tasks(loop)))
```

Please note that you can run selenium in headless mode so you don't need to spawn the whole GUI for calling some simple url.

Comment: Note that this is not a sensible way to use ``asyncio``. As used here, it is just an overblown wrapper around ``ThreadPoolExecutor`` and doesn't add anything. One can directly use the pool's ``map`` or ``submit`` methods instead.