# Best python way to yield back to the event loop to await

Tags: python-3.7, python-asyncio, future

I'm using a library (selenium) that do not implement asyncio and is blocking on I/O taks. When I'm performing several selenium I/O tasks, I am trying to yield back to the event loop in order to be able to do run other asyncio tasks, and the only way I found was to create a task and then await to yield back to the event loop. I wrote my own decorator to help in this process (see the code below). I was wondering if there were better ways to do so?

```py
def task_await(func):
    async def await_func(*args, **kwargs):
        t = asyncio.create_task(func(*args, **kwargs))
        await t
        return t.result()
    return await_func

@task_await
async def foo():
    print('bar')

await foo()
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand the question, but `await asyncio.sleep(0)` is typically the way to yield back to the event loop without I/O to await.

Comment: Thanks, you answer my question. It's much simpler.

Comment: Also, if your code needs to await `sleep(0)` to function, that *usually* points to an architectural issue. If you could edit the question to explain your actual issue rather than the solution you came up with, we might be able to find a better approach to resolve it. (This is sometimes referred to as the [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).)

Comment: Thanks. My issue comes from the fact that I'm using a blocking api in an asyncio app. Thanks to your comment, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303797/python-webdriver-and-asyncio) that points to an asyncio implementation of a webdriver.

Comment: Also, I think I will continue to use @dirn solution as selenium is more documented and my tests are already working.