# Selenium asynchronous wait for page to load

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to run the below function code on 10 tabs. It runs smoothly but my target is not to wait for page to load and to switch to the other tab while the previous tab is loading, as page loading takes a long time.

Here is the function which handles a particular page:

```py
async def search_dial(i,user):
    web.find_element(By.XPATH, 'city_code_box').send_keys(get_citycode(user))
    web.find_element(By.XPATH, 'dial_box').send_keys(get_dial(user))
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    web.find_element(By.NAME, 'click_button_name').click()
```

It should yield to other code while the page loads (the sleep line) and then return to the page.  But at present it blocks on the last line, waiting for the page to load fully.

Here's the code (in reality it includes the function above, and functions irrelevant for this question like `get_citycode`):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
web = webdriver.Chrome('C://Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
web.maximize_window()

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(search_dial(0, tabs[0])) #tabs is an array which holds all tabs window handlers
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(search_dial(1, tabs[1]))
    task3 = asyncio.create_task(search_dial(2, tabs[2]))
    task4 = asyncio.create_task(search_dial(3, tabs[3]))
    task5 = asyncio.create_task(search_dial(4, tabs[4]))
    task6 = asyncio.create_task(search_dial(5, tabs[5]))
    task7 = asyncio.create_task(search_dial(6, tabs[6]))
    task8 = asyncio.create_task(search_dial(7, tabs[7]))
    task9 = asyncio.create_task(search_dial(8, tabs[8]))
    task10 = asyncio.create_task(search_dial(9, tabs[9]))
    await asyncio.gather(task1,task2,task3,task4,task5,task6,task7,task8,task9,task10)

asyncio.run(main())
```

How do I get the page coroutine (`search_dial`) to yield while the page is loading and then return when it is loaded, rather than blocking?

Comment: what do you think it *should* do? What is it doing? N.B. it would be much simpler to avoid unrolling that loop and rewrite your main as `tasks = [asyncio.create_task(search_dial(x, tabs[x]) for x in range(10)]; await asyncio.gather(*tasks)` although that is unrelated to the problem.

Comment: thank you but the problem is that when the code goes to the line

web.find_element(By.NAME, 'click_button_name').click()

it will wait for the page to fully load, this is my problem as the page load in 5 secs average. i need to reduce excution time of the whole program, so it came to my mind to use multitabs with asyncio

Comment: I clarified my comment, sorry. The unrolled loop is ugly IMHO but irrelevant.  However I don't know what the *question* is here: what do you think the code *should* do, and what is it doing?

Comment: AFAIK selenium works one tab at a time.  So if you want to work on a tab I'm pretty sure you have to switch to it.  However without the ability to run the code and without knowing what's going wrong I don't know if this is relevant...

Comment: I have significantly edited the question.  Have I got it right?  Feel free to edit further/revert, but I think this is more the question you're asking?

Comment: the problem is that when it starts at tabs[0] it will wait for the page to fully loaded before switching to tabs[1]. I tried asyncio to overcome this problem with concurrency but same issue arise. this is why i asked that question, how to overcome the page load restrictions and let tab switch while other tab is loading?

Comment: Ah right, I see.  In that case I think my edits do properly capture the question as you see it?  I'll post an answer under that assumption, but do feel free to edit the question---it's yours, after all.

Comment: That's not how ``async`` works. You can only switch between ``async``/``await`` operations; all the blocking Selenium operations cannot be switched out of.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi so there is no way to work around it? I had read that aiohttp works with asyncio properly but it doesn't have the functionality of passing items to text boxes(as far as i knew). so i am totally trapped and the code is not working as intended

Comment: @AhmedTantawy that's a different question: *if* what you want to do can be done *wihout* scraping, by making the http requests yourself, it can certainly be done in python, including with aiohttp (or other asyncio libraries).  That depends on what happens when you press 'submit': if it's a simple form submit it might work.  However many pages add session and authentication cookies to the submit: not impossible to do without loading the page, but scraping is definitely simpler.  Note that 'text boxes' exist only in your browser.  Sooner or later the data is sent to the server somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a misconception here about how selenium/chromedriver works.  The real hold up is in the the `tabs` list, but you don't show us how you generate it.  Each entry is generated by opening a tab and doing something like `web.get(url)`, *which is a blocking operation*.  Asyncio can't do anything about this: it's 'cooperative' multitasking, and requires tasks explicitly to yield control back to the scheduler (with `await`).  Selenium isn't cooperative, so asyncio won't add anything.

I do not know of any cooperative/non blocking operations in selenium.  If the page is taking forever to load it might be enough to add a timeout: frequently what takes forever is some non-essential (to a scraper) image or the like, and the core *content* is already there.  But this depends very much on the page.  Someone might come along with a non-blocking selenium interface; otherwise your only option is to run multiple browsers if you want to parallelise.

See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303797/python-webdriver-and-asyncio) for a discussion of how to do this.

Incidentally note that your main function could be written as:

```py
async def main():
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(search_dial(i, tab) for i, tab in  enumerate(tabs)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tabs)
```

It's not clear whether your `search_dial` really wants to take a window handler and call it `user`: if so the variable could probably be better named.

Comment: so what is your recommendations? should i rewrite my code using another library? if so what should be used? i used selenium for the ease of passing texts to text boxes. is there another library that can do the same and allow concurrency?

Comment: @AhmedTantawy not to my knowledge.  See the linked question for a way to gain concurrency by launching multiple *browsers*, or have a look at how the page works and try to put together some form submission code to skip the page entirely and just submit the data.  I can't advise further without the website (and enough time to play with it).  Or just live with slow loading....

Comment: In principle one could use ``asyncio``'s thread backend to run selenium's synchronous task asynchronously in ``asyncio``. That doesn't really buy anything, and is basically just a complicated way of putting everything into threads directly, though.

Comment: If I were doing this I wouldn't bother with asyncio.  The only use case I can see is if you already have an asyncio framework (e.g. a web server) to plug into---although even then I'd probably just use message passing and a separate pool of workers, which is pretty much what the asyncio thread backend is.

Comment: the website runs through a VPN connection, so i think if you would like to help i would invite you to a share my desktop session to check it life

Comment: @AhmedTantaw sadly I don't have the time, but good luck with it.